# Is it possible to rename return(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) to something different?

Tags: c#

I want to change the names item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 to FunctionSuccessful, Errorline1, Errorline2, Errorline3, Errorline4. How can I do that?

My code doesn't work as expected, because it still returns item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 in the client code instead of the new names FunctionSuccessful, Errorline1, Errorline2, Errorline3, Errorline4:

[image: Client image]

What should I change in my Azure function so that it returns the new names FunctionSuccessful, Errorline1, Errorline2, Errorline3, Errorline4 in the client code?

Azure Function:

```
    [FunctionName("AddUsernamePasswordEmailToAccount")]
    public static async Task<dynamic> NewCall(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
    {
        // ...

        bool functionsuccessful = false;
        string errorline1 = string.Empty;
        string errorline2 = string.Empty;
        string errorline3 = string.Empty;
        string errorline4 = string.Empty;

        var result = await clientAPI.AddUsernamePasswordAsync(request);
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            var errors = OnPlayFabError(result.Error, language);
            errorline1 = errors[0];
            errorline2 = errors[1];
            errorline3 = errors[2];
            errorline4 = errors[3];
        }
        else
        {
            functionsuccessful = true;
        }

        return (FunctionSuccessful: functionsuccessful, Errorline1: errorline1, Errorline2: errorline2, Errorline3: errorline3, Errorline4: errorline4);
    }
```

Client code:

```
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = PlayFabSimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(result.Result.FunctionResult.ToString());
            if (dic.TryGetValue("FunctionSuccessful", out object a))
            {
                addedcredentials = (bool)a;
            }
            if (dic.TryGetValue("Errorline1", out object b))
            {
                errorline1 = (string)b;
            }
            if (dic.TryGetValue("Errorline2", out object c))
            {
                errorline2 = (string)c;
            }
            if (dic.TryGetValue("Errorline3", out object d))
            {
                errorline3 = (string)d;
            }
            if (dic.TryGetValue("Errorline4", out object e))
            {
                errorline4 = (string)e;
            }
```

Comment: When you do `(item1: item1, item2: item2, etc)` you're creating a `Tuple<object1, oject2, etc>`. When serialized, the tuple ends up as a collection of keys and values, and that's what you see. You need to return an object, like `return new { item1, item2, etc };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer to your question

Create your own type, with the properties you want, and return that.

```
public class Result
{
    public bool FunctionSuccessful { get; set; }
    public string Errorline1 { get; set; }
    public string Errorline2 { get; set; }
    public string Errorline3 { get; set; }
    public string Errorline4 { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
return new Result
{
    FunctionSuccessful = functionsuccessful,
    Errorline1 = errorline1,
    Errorline2 = errorline2,
    Errorline3 = errorline3,
    Errorline4 = errorline4
};
```

#### Why does it happen?

I played around with this for a little bit, as I can reproduce your problem, and I found a few interesting things.

Firstly, the reason it's doing this is because the Azure Functions runtime has a dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json`, and it's that package which is serialising the response. Furthermore, if you have a read of the [tuple documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) you'll see:

> The default names of tuple fields are `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3` and so on. **You can always use the default name of a field, even when a field name is specified explicitly or inferred**

Relying on those default names presumably makes supporting tuples much simpler for libraries. If you have a read of [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1230) on the `Newtonsoft.Json` repo, you'll see a discussion whereby people are skeptical of the cost of implementing named tuple fields, as they don't view it as worth the effort.

So, to be clear, I can reproduce your problem in a simple console application:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var functionsuccessful = true;
    var errorline1 = "error 1";
    var errorline2 = "error 2";
    var errorline3 = "error 3";
    var errorline4 = "error 4";

    var result = (FunctionSuccessful: functionsuccessful, 
        Errorline1: errorline1, 
        Errorline2: errorline2, 
        Errorline3: errorline3, 
        Errorline4: errorline4);
    var serialised = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

    Console.WriteLine(serialised);
}
```

which produces the output of:

```
{
    "item1": true,
    "item2": "error 1",
    "item3": "error 2",
    "item4": "error 3",
    "item5": "error 4"
}
```

What I did find interesting though, is serialising with `System.Text.Json` instead:

```
serialised = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(result);
Console.WriteLine(serialised);
```

produces:

```
{}
```

That I can't explain. I'm hesitant to call it a bug, but I definitely didn't expect that.

Edit: After looking into `Seabizkit`'s comment, `ValueTuple` isn't yet supported by `System.Text.Json`, as confirmed by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1519#issuecomment-572751931) and should be added for [.NET 5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41313).

Comment: its because it isnt a type... so its doenst know. and as for the System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(result); doesnt really support dictionarys.. only in the dotnet 5 release has this been added.... so my understanding is it sees `(stuff)` as a dictionary.

Comment: Thanx, it works now. I found out that it is returned like this in the client: "functionSuccessful, errorline1, errorline2, errorline3, errorline4". The first letter is always lowercase letter. But that doesn't matter for me if it is lowercase or capital letter.

Comment: @Jerry61 No problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.
You can use a simple strategy, codificating the string, where the first character is the code.

Codification: String stating with codes

0: Successful

1: Error line 1. The client exception 1 ....

2: Error line 2. The client exception 2 ....

3: Error line 3. The client exception 3 ....

4: Error line 4. The client exception 4 ....

In the Client Side you check first the code, the first character of the string.

string result = s1.Substring(0,1);

And apply a Swicth structure..